# I can't call touchUpInside of button to ViewController when is at a subview

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiviewcontroller, subview

I'm make a library from wallet of cards, but when i am pushing a button in my controller not working, i don't kwon if my instance is bad, need help please.

The repository of project is in github this is the link:
https://github.com/RAES9/WalletOfCards

The name class id WalletOfCards.swift

```
let controller = self.delegate?.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: self.destitaionController as String)
self.delegate?.addChild(controller!)
controller!.didMove(toParent: self.delegate!)
```

> Lines: 143,144,15.
>
> Function: tappedButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new var for my controller and i added new subview in this

```
let controller = self.dataSource.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
self.destitaionController as String)
self.dataSource.addChild(controller)
controller.didMove(toParent: self.dataSource)
controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (cardSelected?.frame.width)!, height: (cardSelected?.frame.height)!)
controller.view.alpha = 0.0
self.dataSource.view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.view.alpha = 1.0
```